# When and how should default.nix, shell.nix and release.nix be used?

Tags: nix, nixos, nixops

One of the first types of Nix expression one encounters when learning how to use the Nix package manager is `default.nix`; on the wonderful NixOS IRC channel I learned of the existence of `shell.nix` and `release.nix` as well.

I got the impression that - roughly -`default.nix` is to be used with `nix-build` for simply building the package, `shell.nix` is used with `nix-shell` to create an interactive environment with the package and `release.nix` is used with `nixops` in deploying the package.

Since this is likely incomplete and partially incorrect, and since this does not seem to be clearly documented, I would like a clear and precise explanation of these sorts of "standard files"; in particular, *for each of these file types* (as well as any other standard files I am missing), I would like to know:

1. What are the typical use cases for such a file? What should they *not* be used for?
2. How is this file type structured typically? What are the minimal requirements for it?
3. Could you show a paradigm example of such a file *within its use context*, i.e. with use instructions and including lines of code needed to use it in the shell or another Nix expression?

As an additional bonus question, I want to know which - if any - of these standard files should be used when installing a package into a NixOS module? How would that be done?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As said by @danbst only `default.nix` and `shell.nix` have special meanings for the nix tooling, out of that there is no real standard and everybody is free to use what fits most their needs.

That said, it doesn't mean you cannot set your own set of rules, personally for a single derivation project I like to arrange nix files in the following manner:

- `default.nix`: Use `callpackage` to import `derivation.nix`.
- `derivation.nix`: nixpkgs style derivation file.
- `shell.nix`: nix-shell file.
- `module.nix`: NixOS module file, import `default.nix`.
- `test.nix`: NixOS test file.
- `release.nix`: Hydra jobset declaration.

We had a talk about this topic at the Tokyo NixOS meetup, an example of a such code organization can be found [here](https://github.com/Tokyo-NixOS/presentations/tree/master/2017/02/examples/binserver).

Comment: Lucidly explained! This should be added to the documentation.

Comment: also: flake.nix for nix flakes

Answer (score 78):

First of all, `default.nix` and `shell.nix` have special meanings in Nix tool, but `release.nix` is a convenience one.

Next, `default.nix` is used as a default file when running `nix-build`, and `shell.nix` is used as a default file when running `nix-shell`. Just like you said.

Next, `default.nix` isn't used only for `nix-build`. For example, [`<nixpkgs/lib/default.nix>`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/lib/default.nix) is used as aggregator for functions, and doesn't contain derivations. So not every `default.nix` is supposed to be "built" (but if `default.nix` is an attribute set of derivations, it will be buildable, and `nix-build` will build all of them).

Next, `nix-shell` **will** use `default.nix` if no `shell.nix` is found.

Next, `default.nix` is used as default file when importing directory. So if you write `x = import ./some/directory;`, then `./some/directory/default.nix` will be imported. That actually should explain why `"nix-build ."` uses `default.nix`.

And finally, there are two common formats for derivations in `default.nix`: derivation, and `callPackage` derivation. You can't `nix-build` the latter. Almost any package in nixpkgs is written in this style, see [`hello`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/56904d7c423f2b13b37fbd29f39bbb4b52bc7824/pkgs/applications/misc/hello/default.nix). But you can 

  `nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> { }; callPackage ./path/to/default.nix { }'`

as a workaround. `nix-shell` also supports this `-E` argument.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful in clarifying default.nix. Unfortunately, it still still incomplete: it still seems to miss a paradigm example of a default.nix used in practice, along with its context of application. I would also still like to hear the same about release.nix and shell.nix.

Comment: no longer true I believe, now nix build will look for a flake.nix

Comment: @David天宇Wong there is a difference between `nix build` and `nix-build` (note the space). The stand-alone `nix` tool is for flakes (and some utilities like `nix show-derivation` etc), while the `nix-*` binaries are for non-flake Nix. Summary: this article is still accurate in Nov 2022, although it could do with a **this is about non-flake Nix** notice.