# What is the `nix-shell` equivalent of `nix-env -f <path-to-my-local-nixpkgs-repo> -iA ...`?

Tags: nix-shell

Or is this only possible by writing a custom `shell.nix`?

<sup>Where `path-to-my-local-nixpkgs-repo` is a directory with a `default.nix` file containing a valid Nix expression. This directory may hold one's personal collection of Nix packages or a local clone of the [Nixpkgs repo](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs). I think [this is the part in the Nix manual where `default.nix` is introduced](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/expressions/arguments-variables.html), but [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088192/when-and-how-should-default-nix-shell-nix-and-release-nix-be-used) seems to be better.</sup>

For example:

```hs
let
  nixpkgs_commit = "f4593ab";
  nixpkgs_sha256 = "01bmiqndp1czwjw87kp21dvxs0zwv7yypqlyp713584iwncxjv0r";
  pinnedNixpkgsGithubURL = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/${nixpkgs_commit}.tar.gz";

  fetchedPinnedTarball =
    builtins.fetchTarball
      { name = "nixpkgs";
        url = pinnedNixpkgsGithubURL;
        sha256 = nixpkgs_sha256;
      }
  ;
in
  { pkgs ? import fetchedPinnedTarball {} }:

  pkgs.mkShell
    { buildInputs = [ pkgs.tor-browser-bundle-bin ]; 
    }
```

---

One might argue that this question is off-topic here, because it asks about command line options, but the solution may only be the above Nix expression (or one provided with `-E`). Anyway, if my argument is flawed, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: See also [What is the equivilent shell.nix for nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A gnused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63966084/what-is-the-equivilent-shell-nix-for-nix-shell-nixpkgs-a-gnused) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ nix-shell -E 'with import path-to-my-local-nixpkgs-repo {}; mkShell { buildInputs = [ tor-browser-bundle-bin PKG2 PKGS3 ]; }'
```

Compared to simple `nix-shell -p '(import path-to-my-local-nixpkgs-repo {}).tor-browser-bundle-bin'` this has the benefit of presenting more than one package.

---

Also, I suggest to replace `import path-to-my-local-nixpkgs-repo {}` with `builtins.filterSource (p: t: baseNameOf p != ".git") path-to-my-local-nixpkgs-repo` to save space from copying `.git` (2 GiB full git clone) for no reason on every change.

Comment: what is the content of my-local-nixpkgs-repo?

Comment: @DaniilIaitskov I updated my question to answer yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ nix-shell -E 'with import path-to-my-local-nixpkgs-clone/default.nix {}; runCommand "dummy" { buildInputs = [ tor-browser-bundle-bin ]; } ""'
```

(Credit goes to [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63966084/what-is-the-equivilent-shell-nix-for-nix-shell-nixpkgs-a-gnused). Thanks a lot @potong for doing this research!)

Answer (score 2):

e.g. to create a nix-shell that includes `perl` using the nixpkgs in `/path/to/your/nixpkgs`:

```
nix-shell -E 'with import (builtins.filterSource (p: t: baseNameOf p != ".git") /path/to/your/nixpkgs) {}; mkShell { buildInputs = [ perl ]; }'
```